# How to read and assign this value to variable in sqlite Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to access static variable from outside class?
this is my code, Url saved in local storage using sqflite, And i want to get the value and print. *Print result is null*

**DatabaseHandler.dart**

```
//GET URL
  Future<List<Url>> getUrl() async{
    var db_connection = await db;
    List<Map> list = await db_connection.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Url");
    List<Url> urls = List();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
      Url url = Url();
      url.id = list[i]['id'];
      url.uniform_resource_locator = list[i]['uniform_resource_locator'];
      urls.add(url);
    }
    return urls;
  }
```

**readUrl.dart**

```
import '...'

Future<List<Url>> getUrlFromCache() async {
  var dbHelper = DBHandlerUrl();
  Future<List<Url>> urls = dbHelper.getUrl();
  return urls;
}
class readUrlTesting extends StatelessWidget {
  static var url;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder<List<Url>>(
              future: getUrlFromCache(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data != null) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                   url = snapshot.data[1].uniform_resource_locator;
                    return Text(url);
                  }
                  return Container(
                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );

                }
              });
  }
}
```

**LoginScreen.dart**

If user press button  I want to display Url in console.

```
child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: ()
            print(readUrlTesting.url);),
```

Comment: see https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-app-architecture-101-vanilla-scoped-model-bloc-7eff7b2baf7e and use `Scoped Model` for example

Comment: @pskink How am I do it using Scoped Model? I read article I have no idea

Comment: there is a smaple code in the link i posted above, see `UserModelScreen` class

Comment: Do it need to use FutureBuilder also?

Comment: no, you dont have to

Comment: I can;t understand. It doesn't work with sqlite database

Comment: what you cant understand? how `Future`s work? if so, read [this](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures) first

Answer (score 1):

According to the [FutureBuilder documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) the future should be obtained in StatelessWidget.build method (which you are using). You will either have to pass the future to the constructor of this widget or change the widget to a StatefulWidget and obtain future in the State.initState method.

Hope that helps.

Also, are you using a FutureBuilder just to get the value from futures? If so you can use `await` in async methods or `.then` on future objects.